# Go back to main activity of APP with onBackPressed() AFTER going to that activity from another APP

Tags: android

I want to know if there is a way to get back to the main Activity of one APP using backpressed on another activity when this activity was started from another APP.

Open 1st app that is a barcode reader, get barcode and then use a button that opens another app. How do i get back to the MainActivity by going "back".

Example:

App A || Activity 1 -> Activity 2

APP B || Activity 3 [Goes to App A] -> Activity 2  [Press Back] -> Activity 1 [OF App A, was not opened in this series of events]

Comment: I want to stay on App A and i want to go to the MainActivity of it even though i have never been on this activity before.

Answer (score 0):

Just use
    finish();
on your Activity 2 while you switch to another app from your app A, i.e. just kill the second activity of first app when using intent to switch to another activity.

Comment: I want to stay on App A, in your case i would kill my App instead of going to the MainActivity of it